# AutoComplete TextBox with Entity Framework C#

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, autocomplete

I want to set the autocomplete to the textbox using LINQ to entities.

This my code:

```
using (Reference_TraductionEntities context = new Reference_TraductionEntities())
        {
           var query= from a in context.Feuil1Prenom select a.PRENOMF;      


            AutoCompleteStringCollection sourcename = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();

            sourcename.AddRange(query.ToArray());

            textBox1.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.Suggest;
            textBox1.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
            textBox1.AutoCompleteCustomSource = sourcename;
```

I get ERROR: vshost32.exe stopped working!!

Note: My table Feuil1Prenom  have a very large number of variables:
 * PRENOMF : names: Paul, Johnson, Paulo, .......

Thanks,

Comment: What line crashes? Does a simple filtered query work?

Comment: i do Debug  my CODE, i haven't any crashes...

1) for Debug line: sourcename.AddRange(query.ToArray());  I have : Count 38981 (numbers of names in my database

2) for Debug line which contains textbox1. ..: I have texbox1=""  

then the execution of my application terminates without any error..
And when i want to try write in texbox any character , the craches appears !!!

** the Autocomplete in textbox have any limits numbers ?
Or  my code is not complete ?

Thanks

Comment: Shouldn't be any limit, but you could easily test that by adding a WHERE to your select.

Comment: ٍVery Thanks!
i add where..so i have good result, but not for all the Table : I want whatever the letter entered in the textbox, i have autocomplete,

with my code , i have just autocomplete for word Start With "i", 
 
     `var name = from a in context.Feuil1Prenom
                       where a.PRENOMF.StartsWith("i")
                      select a.PRENOMF;`` 
How can fix it?
Thanks,